# Custom text-only header

Tags: custom-field, wp-admin, custom-header

I am developing a WordPress theme and would like to make use of a custom header on a the homepage (I'm using a custom page template).

I would like this header to **not** include an image, but rather an `<h1>` and `<h2>` tag, and a link.

So my question is the following - how do I go about providing users with the facility to update the headings and the link in the header from the admin backend? Would  [`add_theme_support( 'custom-header' );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers) be suitable for this since I need to add my own fields? And how would I go about completely disabling support for the image and showing the text in my page template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### File: `functions.php`

It's as easy as adding this to your functions.php file (of course having `$wpse67109` set).

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $wpse67109_defaults );
```

### File: `index.php` or any other template

Simply don't add the whole `get_head_image()` and `get_custom_header()->foo` stuff anywhere.

Your headline template part could look like the following example:

```
<header>
    <hgroup>
        <h1 class="site-title">
            <?php
            if ( display_header_text() )
            {
                printf(
                     '<a href="%s" title="%s" rel="home">%s</a>'
                    ,esc_url( home_url( '/' ) )
                    ,esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) )
                    ,get_bloginfo( 'name' )
                );
            } 
            ?>
        </h1>
        <?php if ( '' !== get_bloginfo( 'description' ) ) : ?>
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </hgroup>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Ok, I'll give this a shot - just to clarify though, '$wpse67109_defaults' is the name of the array you used to set the settings for the custom header right?

Comment: @IanMuscat Right. I just prefix such stuff for questions in here.

Comment: Hi, I tried out the example you provided me with - However I didn't get as far as I intended... While the code you gave above removes the image, I am still confused as to how I should insert my custom fields into the header area - I need to give the functionality to users to change the content that's in `<h1>` and `<h2>`. I found [this tutorial](https://illuminatikarate.com/blog/add-your-own-options-to-wordpress-custom-header-image-screen/) - I'll give it a try and see where it takes me...

Comment: @IanMuscat What? Why? _Nooo°°...._ ! Just use the theme customizer with above code ↑. It's as easy as that.

Comment: I must be missing something, sorry for being so green, I'm sort of new to this... I'm not sure if I explained myself clearly... My objective is to have the whole default header image with three textboxes in the admin - one that will contain the h1, one with the h2 and another with the link - that way a user can edit the text from the back-end and it will show up dynamically on the front-end... Is this achievable code you posted above? - Once again, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @IanMuscat Did you try it already?

Comment: Yes, I tried your example... However, my objective is to have three text fields in the admin so users can update it from there...

Comment: And the "Theme Customiser" allows two of them. The third: URl should be set programatically (use conditionals).

Comment: I finally figured out what you meant! You are right this is way easier - I wasn't looking at this through the new customizer but rather under the 'Header' tab of the 'Appearance' menu. Is there a way of achieving the same thing under the menu I mentioned? If not, would it be possible to hide it so users don't get confused? - Still have to figure out the link though - The intention was that users can set it dynamically, but perhaps I can do something a bit different... Once again, thanks so much!

Comment: You can do all funky things with the "Theme Customizer". There're lots of tutorials around it. Accessing the data via `get_theme_mod()` is easy later on.

Comment: Ok, I will look into it... Thank you for your time and patience...